# jquery validation. custom rules using selector syntax

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I'm writing a system utilizing jQuery Validation that pulls in custom rules, messages via jSON  and dynamically validates multiple forms in single pages. All is going swimmingly except I cannot find any decent information on the correct syntax for custom rules....

For example:

I know this works....

```
"ui_txt_GCPostcode": {
    "required": "input[name=ui_rb_ItemAddress][value=Recipient]:checked"
}
```

I'm saying here that `ui_txt_GCPostcode` is required only when a radio button from a list with the name `ui_rb_ItemAddress` and the value `Recipient` is checked.

This to me looks like I am able to assign ruled based upon [dependency expressions](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required#dependency-expression) containing specific selector attributes.

This however doesn't work.....

```
"ui_sel_PCSelect": {
        "required": "input[name=ui_txt_PostCodeSearch]:hidden, input[name=ui_txt_Address]:hidden"
    }
```

The validator is firing even though I have `ui_txt_Address` visible.

I'm even setting up the validator with the [ignore](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options) hidden property eg.

```
                // Validate the form once the defaults are set.
                $validator = $form.validate({
                    // This prevents validation from running on every
                    // form submission by default.
                    onsubmit: false,
                    messages: messages,
                    rules: rules,
                    errorContainer: $container,
                    errorLabelContainer: $("ol", $container),
                    wrapper: "li",

                    // Ignore hidden items. Why is this not working??
                    ignore: ":hidden"
                });
```

Any ideas?? I'm on a pretty tight deadline and I'm starting to panic.

Comment: Do you want `ui_sel_PCSelect` to be `required` when `input[name=ui_txt_PostCodeSearch]` **and**  `input[name=ui_txt_Address]` are hidden?

Comment: @Andrew: Yeah... Exactly that.I've managed to fudge around it just now but I'd like to have a clean robust solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This selector:

```
"input[name=ui_txt_PostCodeSearch]:hidden, input[name=ui_txt_Address]:hidden"
```

Will trigger the `required` rule if either the first **or** second part are true (see the [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)). This is why the rule fires even if one is visible.

If you want to make the element required if *both* are hidden, you may have to supply a dependency-function instead of an expression:

```
"ui_txt_GCPostcode": {
    "required": function() {
        return $("input[name='ui_rb_ItemAddress'][value='Recipient']:checked").length &&
            $("input[name='ui_rb_ItemAddress'][value='Recipient']:checked").length;
    }
}
```

As for the `ignore` property not working, that's for ignoring fields matching the selector (so `:hidden` will tell validator not to validate hidden fields). Not sure if you were using it this way.